# After using cURL to log into a remote webpage, how can I then access another webpage and return it as a string?

Tags: php, curl

Okay, I'm pretty new to cURL. I've managed to log into a webpage using cURL and sending POST data, but once I'm logged in, I'd like it to load various webpages under the same `SESSION` and extract data as a string, so that I can check if the webpage contains a specific string.

How would I go about doing this?

For example:

It logs into `http://example.com/login.php`

But after logging on, I need it to visit `http://example.com/site.php?page=news` and return the contents of that page as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It generally depends on how the remote site handles state management.

In most cases, this will be via a cookie, so you'll need to instruct curl to keep track of cookies.

Something like:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookies');  //where to write cookies received from server
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookies'); //where to read cookies to send in requests.
```

ought to get you started there.

**EDIT**
Blatant Copy/Paste Example ([from here](http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-4277.html) - found with about 20 seconds of googling "php curl login").  This looks to be about right:

```
<?php 
$url ="http://login.yahoo.com/config/login?.src=ym&.intl=us&.partner=&.done=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.yahoo.com%2F"; 
$ch = curl_init();      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/temp/cookie.txt'); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "login=emailid&passwd=password&&submit=Sign In"); 
ob_start();      
curl_exec ($ch); 
ob_end_clean();  
curl_close ($ch); 
unset($ch); 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/temp/cookie.txt"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://us.f515.mail.yahoo.com/ym/login?"); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

curl_close ($ch); 
echo $result;
```

Comment: Well, beforehand I need to know how to make cURL access another webpage prior to ending the script

Comment: You simply make another cURL request, but this time, don't POST, just GET.  Make sure that CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE is set for that second request, so that the second request sends the cookies set during your first (POST) request.

Comment: Sorry, I'm too busy today to work up a working example for you.  But if you're already making one request (to log in), just make sure you're setting the cookiejar up for the login, and then make a second request, pointing cookiefile at the same file, to GET the page you want.  Then inspect the response body for the string you're testing for.